# Why did Yondu need Groot to get his Fin back if he said he controls the arrow with his heart?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In [Guardians of the Galaxy 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2), there is that famous scene where Yondu and Rocket try to tell Groot what Yondu's Fin look like and for him to go get it.

The point of all this is for Yondu to be able to control his arrow and get them out of the cell. But later in the movie Yondu tells Peter:

> I don't use my head to fly the arrow boy, I use my heart.

**So what was the point of him needing the fin in the previous scene?**

My guess is that he needs the fin to control the arrow better or something like that.

Comment: He said that metaphorically I suppose

Comment: @AnkitSharma I don't think so, at one of the post-credits scene we see Kraglin trying to control the arrow with his mind and failing. *Probably* because he is not using his heart.

Comment: no, Ankit's definitely right. It's a clear and obvious English metaphor that means 'don't think to hard about it, just do what feels right'. Kraglin just sucks at it.

Comment: Drax asking this question would have been a great post credits scene. Everyone would have got in a muddle struggling to explain the metaphor, each explanation slightly more confusing than the last one, and after a few minutes Drax would say "Oh, I understand it now. *[pause]* In Yondu's species, the heart is located inside the cranium". Then fade to black while everyone shouts out in exasperation

Comment: Ha, I definitely didn't hear "heart" when I watched it. I thought he said another (unmentionable) body part, which would have made a great allusion to Peter and Rocket's conversation about piloting with that same body part.

Comment: I thought he was controlling it with his eyes and by wisteling lol.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the line of dialogue. He needs the Fin in order to get access to the arrow. When he's 'aiming' or 'firing' he does it instinctively, not by *thinking about what he's doing*. It's similar to athletes who access their muscle memory to perform a task.

Comment: You might want to emphasize that *head* here refers to his brain, not the fin. The fin is still a necessary part, it’s that he’s “feeling” what he needs to send through the fin rather than thinking it all out.

Comment: As an image: The fin is the small led you have on old remote control (for the  infra-red). The buttons/fingers on the buttons are controlled/send by its  thoughts. The fact that is does it with its heart instead of its brain is just metaphorical. So without the fin it can't access the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the fin as just the transmitter / antenna combo. You still have to feed the transmitter commands to forward on to the receiver, right? That's what comes from his heart... The commands.